# Failed to Stop Bean during server shutdown

Tags: java, spring

I have a war file that utilizes spring and stomp messages. Everything works great but during shutdown or restart I see hundreds of lines like:

```
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.929 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.929 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.929 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.929 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.929 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.930 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.930 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.930 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.930 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.930 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.931 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.931 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.931 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.931 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.931 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.932 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.932 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.932 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.932 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.933 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.933 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 0
07-Feb-2018 12:21:35.933 [INFO ] Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
07-Feb-2018 12:21:36.394 [WARN ] Failed to stop bean 'accountEventPublisher'
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
```

My accountEventPublisher bean publishes events to allow other parts of the server to intercept the event and act on it.

This is my accountEventPublisherBean:

```
@Configuration
public class AccountEventPublisherConfig {

  public static final String MULTICAST_NAME = "accountEventMulticaster";

  public static final String EVENT_PUBLISHER_NAME ="accountEventPublisher";

  @Autowired 
  private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

  @Bean(name=MULTICAST_NAME)
  public ApplicationEventMulticaster simpleApplicationEventMulticaster() {
    SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster eventMulticaster = new SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster();
    eventMulticaster.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    return eventMulticaster;
  }

  @Bean(name=EVENT_PUBLISHER_NAME)
  public ApplicationEventPublisher simplePublisher() {
    return publisher;
  }
}
```

I then use it in my static CommService to send events:

```
@Service
public class CommService {
  private static ApplicationEventPublisher accountEventPublisher;

  public static void sendEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
    if (accountEventPublisher== null) {
      accountEventPublisher = (ApplicationEventPublisher) ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(AccountEventPublisherConfig.EVENT_PUBLISHER_NAME);
    }
    accountEventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
  }
}
```

The following code is what intercepts the events

```
@Component
public class FileUploadTriggerListener implements ApplicationListener<AccountTrigger> {

  @Autowired
  private PatchFileService fileService;

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationLogService appLogService;

  @Autowired
  private ExecutorService executor;

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(AccountTrigger trigger) {
    if (trigger.getType() != TriggerType.FILE_UPLOADED) return;
    executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         System.out.println("Hello World");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And Here is the Class that extends `ApplicationEvent`

```
public class AccountTrigger extends ApplicationEvent {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2139401946845273241L;

  private Integer userId;

  private TriggerType type;

  private List<Object> resources = new ArrayList<>();

  public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
  }

  public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
  }

  public List<Object> getResources() {
    return resources;
  }

  public void setResources(List<Object> resources) {
    this.resources = resources;
  }

  public TriggerType getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(TriggerType type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

All ApplicationEvents are of type `AccountTrigger` with an enumeration of trigger types. The only trigger type I use right now is `FILE_UPLOAD`.

I am not sure why this bean won't stop and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the `ApplicationEventPublisher` class.  Does it manage resources which need to be closed?

Comment: `ApplicationEventPublisher` is an interface provided by spring and I got an example from http://www.baeldung.com/spring-events. I added the code that intercepts the events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved here since it doesn't fit in a comment. I could not prove but what seems to be happening:

`AccountEventPublisherConfig.publisher` is the application context.

But also, `AccountEventPublisherConfig.simplePublisher()` creates a managed bean named "accountEventPublisher" which is essentially an alias for the application context.

When stopping the app, the context is attempting to close the "accountEventPublisher" bean, which is itself.  This probably results in a recursive call ending with the StackOverflowError.

Try removing the definition of the "accountEventPublisher" bean.  And in the Service:

```
@Autowired 
private ApplicationEventPublisher accountEventPublisher;
```

and directly publish:

```
public static void sendEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
     accountEventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, I never thought about that. It makes sense. I did figure out another way to fix the issue using `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` but your comment explains what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem. I ended up having to change my configuration class to a component and implement `ApplicationEventPublisherAware`

```
@Component
public class AccountEventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

  public static final String EVENT_PUBLISHER_NAME ="accountEventPublisher";

  private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

  public void publishEvent(AccountTrigger event) {
    publisher.publishEvent(event);
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
    publisher = applicationEventPublisher;
  }
}
```

Then I fixed my references to the other publisher and it seemed to work. No longer getting the errors.